# Sterling Archer in Destiny 2?

Tags: destiny-2

I love Destiny 2, and I love Archer, so imagine my surprise when I'm watching Parks and Recreation, and I hear the voice of Archer, so I looked up H. Jon Benjamin on IMDB and saw that he was a voice actor in Destiny 2, listed as a Radio Voice. I looked around and couldn't find where he appeared in game. Can anyone tell me where his voice appears?

Comment: He is supposedly heard over the radio on Titan randomly. Not much information other than that. [reddit link](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/6yr4fr/during_the_credits_h_jon_benjamin_is_listed/)

Comment: Even IMDB just lists it as a random radio voice. It was more a cameo than anything else.